# leafletjs page jumps on layer click

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

I have a leaflet map with group layers positioned outside of it. When I scroll past the map and click on one of the checkboxes, the page jumps to the top of the map. Why would that happen?

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [51.501617,-0.018582],
    zoom: 14
});

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'jeffceriello.nd7obhnh',
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiamVmZmNlcmllbGxvIiwiYSI6Ikhrakxrd00ifQ.SlVngzIXeS5UPC8UGmy1OA'
}).addTo(map);

map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();

// marker
var churchill = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '/img/pin.png',
    shadowUrl: '',

    iconSize:     [43, 64], // size of the icon
    shadowSize:   [0, 0], // size of the shadow
    iconAnchor:   [21, 64], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [0, 0],  // the same for the shadow
    popupAnchor:  [0, 0] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});

L.marker([51.503754,-0.014841], {icon: churchill}).addTo(map);

var geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-0.014782, 51.504711]
             },
            "properties": {
                "title": "Barclays Bank",
                markerColor: "#6D8AAA"
            }
        },{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-0.014618, 51.504648]
            },
            "properties": {
                "title": "Idea Store",
                markerColor: "#6D8AAA"
            }
        },{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-0.014532, 51.504556]
            },
            "properties": {
                "title": "James Shoe Care",
                markerColor: "#6D8AAA"
            }
        }
]};

shopping = L.geoJson(geojson, {
    style: function(feature) {
        return {color: feature.properties.markerColor};
    },
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {radius: 8, fillOpacity: 1, stroke: false});
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.title);
    }
});

map.addLayer(shopping);

var geojson2 = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-0.014546, 51.504319]
        },
        "properties": {
            "title": "Birleys",
            "markerColor": "#6D8AAA"
        }
    }
]};

food = L.geoJson(geojson2, {
    style: function(feature) {
        return {color: feature.properties.markerColor};
    },
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {radius: 8, fillOpacity: 1, stroke: false});
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.title);
    }
});

//map.addLayer(food);

var overlayMaps = {
    "Shopping": shopping,
    "Food & Drink": food
};

var control = L.control.layers(overlayMaps, null, {collapsed: false});
control.addTo(map);
control._container.remove();

document.getElementById('layers').appendChild(control.onAdd(map));
```

[And here is a JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/o502bgn5/2/)

Comment: Probably because you took a `L.Control` meant for on-map usage and manipulated it with `control._container.remove();`? If you want an off-map control, why not code that instead?

Comment: were you able to fix it. I'm having same issue

Answer (score 1):

This is a known behaviour, specific to Chrome browser, as described in [Leaflet/Leaflet#4125](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4125#issuecomment-356289643):

> this is a specific behaviour of Chrome / Chromium browser (not specific to Leaflet) when an Element is focused, whether programmatically (as done by Leaflet) or through Tab key press: Chrome will scroll to make the Element fully visible (or to its top, in case it is bigger than the window view port), even if it is already partially visible.
>
> Whereas other browsers will scroll only if the Element is not visible at all.

You can prevent Leaflet from focusing the map when using the Control, e.g. with the workaround provided in the link:

```js
L.Control.include({
  _refocusOnMap: L.Util.falseFn // Do nothing.
});
```

Updated JSFiddle including this workaround, showing that the page no longer scrolls in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/1byx9ejh/

---

Note: as implied by snkashis' comment on the question, this is made especially visible because a built-in Leaflet Layers Control is used but extracted outside of the map.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get it to work using "_refocusOnMap" as suggested by ghybs. Currently, this is the only thing that worked  for me:

```
document.getElementById('mapHolder').focus();
```

It's not elegant and it still "jumps", but at least I can make it happen behind a loading screen.

Comment: Seems like your situation is actually different from OP. Please feel free to make it a separate question with details of your specific setup.